# Android studio перестала предлагать вариант для import класса

Tags: android, android-studio

Андроид студио перестала предлагать импортировать в класс некоторые библиотеки, например при написании `ConstraintLayout`, он не понимает, что это пока вручную не прописать импорт, тоже самое с `RecyclerView` в gradle зависимости есть, Clean Rebuild проекта делал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Измените язык - переключите с русского на английский.

**UPD**

Для решения проблемы необходимо было удалить "android.support" из секции "Exclude from Import and Completetion" (из вкладки "File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import"). В настройках этот пакет был исключен для импорта и автодополнения, а `ConstraintLayout` и `RecyclerView` находятся как раз в этом пакете.

Comment: Такой вариант не помог(

Comment: @Александр, а где вы изменили язык?

Comment: В системе , а где ещё?

Comment: @Александр, а можете добавить в пост скриншот вашего окна "File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import" ?

Comment: как тут кидать скриншот не знаю, в разделе java везде стоят галки  кроме "add unambiguous imports on the fly " в Exclude from Import and Completetion android.supprot --- Scope IDE

Comment: @Александр, а попробуйте удалить  " android.supprot" из "Exclude from Import and Completetion" и снять галку с "Optimize imports on the fly". После этого проблема остаётся?

Comment: Да спасибо , помогло!

Comment: Проблема и была как раз в "android.support" - в настройках этот пакет был исключен для импорта и автодополнения, а ConstraintLayout и RecyclerView находятся ка раз в этом пакете.

Comment: видимо случайно сделал исключение этого пакета, спасибо большое

Comment: @pavlofff, обновила ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Сходите на *File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> Java* и поиграйте с флажками.

Альтернативно, можно выбирать курсором нераспознанный класс и нажимать *alt-enter* и Студия предложит набор вариантов для импорта. Вообще *alt-enter* обладает многими чудесными свойствами, например с его помощью текстовые строки можно пихать сразу в ресурсы и проч.

Comment: Я как раз таки и говорю про alt enter он не предлагает выбор выше указанных ConstraintLayout и RecyclerView